# Handling IO operations through a server and building the UI using a separate framework/application

Tags: server, ui, io, rust

I am trying to build a file editor, and I wanted to build the UI using Flutter. However I wanted to implement IO operations (reading a file, applying changes, etc) in Rust.

The reason I would like to use Rust is that it would be faster for expensive operations and also seems to have a better serialization framework (through serde https://serde.rs/) than Dart (which appears to have just json_serializable).

My approach is currently setting up a Server using the Rocket Framework (https://rocket.rs/), which creates a server on port 8080. My idea is that I can make request in flutter using the http package (or any other package) and listen to these request in Rust. I noticed VSCode and other editors use a similar approach for language-tied operations (with LSP).

For example one way I could rename a file would be to create a POST request on the /rename route with the old file name and the new name as the parameters.

Is this frontend-backend decoupling a common/canonical approach, or are there any downsides to it?

I am quite new to this domain, so I apologize for any theoretical errors or wrong terms I might have used.

Comment: Sounds pretty convoluted

Comment: Agreed with whatsisname, there doesn't seem to be any good reason for splitting any kind of single-device app whose interaction is limited entirely just to the user's own device and operating system (managing their local filesystem in this case).  Ultimately you are not hiding/protecting anything nor are you gaining any kind of separation - just adding a whole load of unnecessary barriers between the app itself and the underlying operating system.  Generally speaking if an app needs to do something to the OS, then the best place to do that is within the app itself, not another process.

Comment: Also note that programming languages and runtimes cannot do anything to affect the speed of calls into the filesystem/operating system, so a file I/O operation cannot magically get any faster just because you call it from Rust.

Comment: ah ok, thank you, however, the operations I wanted to do in rust are not just IO operations, but also more complex ones, for example search stuff in a large file, compute values, etc. Another reason I wanted to split the architecture is that I wuld like to support editing off the cloud (in this way I could share the code between the local and remote development). With this in mind is it still considered a bad architectural choice?

Comment: "Search stuff in a large file" will still be I/O bound. "Compute values" is honestly so vague as to be meaningless. On the other hand, "support editing [in] the cloud" sounds like a very valid reason for a split architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing languages is fine, but using sockets is poor design. You have a program that is split into two parts and one part reaches outside of itself to find the other part. There is a significant possibility that it finds the wrong part. If I start your program twice, does one of the backends fail because the port is already in use, and then both frontends connect to the same backend? Can a malicious user bind to the backend port before the backend starts, then trick the frontend into showing false info? Can a malicious user connect to the backend and make it delete all your files? What if I am already running a web server on port 8080? (And yes, language servers also have similar concerns)

You *could* solve these things, but it's better to make sure they aren't problems to begin with - find a way to mix languages that doesn't force you to split the program into two parts and use sockets. One possibility is to change the sockets to something that isn't sockets, such as [anonymous pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/anonymous-pipe-operations) (Windows) which can be inherited by a child process without needing a port number.

But the best way is to mix the different languages in the same program so you don't need to split it up to begin with. To mix different languages in the same program, you are looking for a *foreign function interface* which is a way to call one language from a different one.

It's very common that C is the "lowest common denominator". A great number of languages (including Flutter) are able to call C functions, and fewer languages (including Rust) are able to write functions that look like C functions. [Here's something I found about calling C functions from Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/c-interop), and [here's something I found about writing a C library in Rust](http://blog.asleson.org/2021/02/23/how-to-writing-a-c-shared-library-in-rust/). By putting the right pieces together you should be able to write a shared library in Rust that looks like it's written in C, and then call it from Flutter.

Note that you don't need all of the pieces from these two pages. Since you aren't actually writing a C program you don't need a header file to tell the C compiler what functions are in the library, but you do need something in Flutter to tell the Flutter compiler what functions are in the library. And since it's written in Rust, you'll probably find it better to build the library with cargo instead of cmake. It will probably take a bit of trial and error to find a compile workflow that works for you.